# How to change current Plot Window Size (in R)

Tags: graphics, r, window, plot, radix

For example. Assume I do:

```
dev.new(width=5, height=4)
plot(1:20)
```

And now I wish to do

```
plot(1:40)
```

But I want a bigger window for it.

I would guess that the way to do it would be (assuming I don't want to open a new window) to do

```
plot(1:40, width=10, height=4)
```

Which of course doesn't work.

The only solution I see to it would be to turn off the window and start a new one. (Which will end my plotting history)

Is there a better way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Tal-from your example (increase in width by 2x) it seems you want to be able to substantially increase the plot area. If it's a smaller increase in plot area you want, then you can move the four margins back, e.g., par(mar=c(3.0, 3.0, 1.5, 1.5))

Comment: You want to resize the current window?

Comment: Once the window is opened, it "belongs" to the window manager. I am not aware of any call that allows you to resize and already-opened window.  You could cheat and simulate in code the 'mouse activates windows and enlarges' but it strikes me as having a poor cost/benefit ratio.

Comment: Hello Doug, Shane and Firk - Thank you for answering.

My situation is that I am to give a lecture on R.  And in that lecture I intend to move between: par(mfrow = c(1,1)) to par(mfrow = c(1,2)) back and forth. Which will damage the image proportions and will force me to resize the window.

The only solution I found for doing this in the code was by closing and opening a new window but that removes my ability to store the history of the plots.

I hope my question was clearer now.

Best,
Tal

Comment: help(dev.new) and help(dev.set)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a my solution to this:

```
resize.win <- function(Width=6, Height=6)
{
        # works for windows
    dev.off(); # dev.new(width=6, height=6)
    windows(record=TRUE, width=Width, height=Height)
}
resize.win(5,5)
plot(rnorm(100))
resize.win(10,10)
plot(rnorm(100))
```

Comment: That would be 'works only for Windows'. No other system has a function `windows` as Brian Ripley tried to explain to you.

Comment: Hi Dirk,
Thanks for mentioning this (also notice I wrote it in the code).
But I guess this is something too...

Best,
Tal

Answer (score 13):

Some workaround could be rather than using dev.new() R function use this function which should work across platform  :

```
 dev.new <- function(width = 7, height = 7) 
 { platform <- sessionInfo()$platform if (grepl("linux",platform)) 
 { x11(width=width, height=height) } 
 else if (grepl("pc",platform)) 
 { windows(width=width, height=height) } 
 else if (grepl("apple", platform)) 
 { quartz(width=width, height=height) } }
```

Comment: `sessionInfo()$platform` returns `"x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)"` on my system.