# Python and rpy2: How do I adjust/clear a graphic during runtime?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 to do data analysis and plotting in python. It works fine except for the fact that when I draw a plot, it's window hangs around until the program terminates. Is there a way to clear the plot during runtime? Additionally, If I ever resize the window, the plot disappears, but the window remains. When using R interactively, resizing the window simply adjusts the size of my plot. I'd like to have this functionality within python.

For example, were I to run the following code, I would be presented with a simple plot.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robj

xdata = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
ydata = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Rxdata = robj.IntVector(xdata)
Rydata = robj.IntVector(ydata)

plot = robj.r.plot
plot(x=Rxdata, y=Rydata, main='title')
```

however, if I wanted to resize the window, the plot would dissapear, and if I want my code to keep doing other things, this window hangs around. If there is a command that works in R to clear the plot that might work, but I can't seem to find one. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following commands to control the plot window interatively:

```
dev.new() # opens a new window, and can control the size
dev.off() # closes the window
```

As an example, see these questions:

- [Creating a Plot Window of a Particular Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129952/creating-a-plot-window-of-a-particular-size)
- [How to change current Plot Window Size (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367328/how-to-change-current-plot-window-size-in-r)
- [How to separate two  plots in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801064/how-to-separate-two-plots-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Check the rpy2 documentation about [processing interactive events](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/rinterface.html#rinterface-interactive-processevents)