# Shrink y axis width

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to shrink y-axis? I mean instead of the plot being square, I want it to be rectangular, with y axis shrinked.

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(rnorm(10000))
colnames(data) = "numOfX"
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=numOfX))
m + geom_histogram(colour = "blue", fill = "white", binwidth = 0.5)
```

Comment: You can save the image in whatever dimensions you want by specifying the `width` and `height` arguments in `ggsave`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
last_plot() + opts(aspect.ratio=1/10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the margins by adding the following to the last line of your code:

```
+ opts(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,10,1), "lines"))
```

The numbers are the number of lines to add to the margin in the order c(top, right, bottom, left).

**Update:** The methods that baptiste and I discussed will change the size of the plot itself, but not the size of the plot area. Just for completeness, if you want to change the aspect ratio of the plot but still have it fill the whole plot area, then you need to change the size of the plot area itself.

On the Mac you can do `quartz(width=w, height=h)`, with width and height in inches. This will open a plot window of the specified size. Then run your original code (without margin or aspect ratio changes). This will give you whatever plot size you wish and the plot will fill the plotting area. You can use `dev.off()` to close the Quartz window when you're done with it.

You can do the same thing in Windows using [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367328/how-to-change-current-plot-window-size-in-r).

Finally, if you're using RStudio, you can do Export-->Copy-to-Clipboard and then adjust the aspect ratio manually.

Of course, you can use a combination of my or baptiste's original answers along with the methods above to control both the size of the plot area and the size of the margins at the same time.

Comment: Showing following error: Error in structure(list(...), class = "options") : 
  could not find function "unit"