# How to change the plot window size at R permanently?

Tags: r, plot, window

I use 13' MacBook Pro Retina but when I tried plotting on the screen, it uses 7x7 inches plot size at default. This is beyond the vertical limit of the screen and hence I have to bother resizing the plotted window any time I plot because the x-label isn't displayed without resizing it.

But how can I do it? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367328/how-to-change-current-plot-window-size-in-r) uses `windows()` function but there is no such function available in my system!

Also, even if it is available, it seems that I still have to execute the command every time I plot, which is so annoying.

I want to set the size permanently. How can I do it?

Comment: The equivalent of `windows()` is `quartz()` for Mac as per the answer by Purnendumaity (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310665/5282315), however that's not a permanent setting.

Comment: @GwenaëlGouérou Thanks. I overlooked it.

Comment: I tried using  `quartz()` as suggested above but I have a pathological hatred for calling it every time I plot. It is so insufferable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it took me some times to find it, it was simply written at the very bottom of the documentation for [quartz](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/quartz.html).

**To permanently change the default settings**, you just need to **include a line in your .Rprofile** :

**For a Mac solution :**

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
        function(...) grDevices::quartz.options(width = 6, height = 6))
```

You can then modify the default 7x7 width and height to whatever will suit your screen best.

**For a Windows solution :**

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),  
        function(...) grDevices::windows.options(width = 6, height = 6))
```

**For a [X-window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) solution :**

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),  
        function(...) grDevices::X11.options(width = 6, height = 6))
```

*As for the .Rprofile file, it should be located in your start-up working directory.*

*If it doesn't exist, you can create a new one with your normal text editor but be sure to save it as .Rprofile (note the .) not as a .txt file.*

*You can also create it directly from RStudio :*

*- New File -> Text File*
*- write the code above inside it*
*- Save it with the name .RProfile*
*- quit and restart Rstudio*

*(or quit and restart R if you're working from the command line)*

*Note also that R will look for this file first in the current working directory, then in the user's home directory.*

Comment: For the Windows solution, should it be `grDevices::windows.options`?

Comment: Correct, X11.options() is for X-window systems not Windows, I'll edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Terrific. It worked like a charm! And don't sorry; it also took me so much but I had still failed to get the answer...